# Looking for a way to do a File Search on files with differing extensions

Tags: delphi

I want to do a search for files with an extension of .zip or .bak.
This is my attempt:

```
var s: TSearchRec;
  function FindArchive: boolean;
  begin
    Result := FindFirst(Archive + '*.bak', faNormal + faReadOnly, s) = 0;
    if not Result then begin
      FindClose(s);
      Result := FindFirst(Archive + '*.zip', faNormal + faReadOnly, s) = 0;
    end;
  end;
```

This only returns items matching the first item i.e.*.bak.  I have tried it with and without the FindClose but the results are the same.  Normally the FindClose would be called by the calling routine.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you want both then don't put a condition (`if`) to the second and call both, unrelated to if the first is successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my example:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils, System.StrUtils;
var
  Dir,
  c   :  string;
begin
  try
    Dir := 'C:\abc'; //The search directory
    for c in TDirectory.GetFiles(Dir, '*.*',
         function (const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
         begin
           Result := IndexText(ExtractFileExt(SearchRec.Name).ToLower, ['.zip', '.bak']) >= 0;
         end) do
    begin
      writeln(c);
    end;
    readln(c);
  except
     on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Just note that this approach builds up the entire file list in memory before you get a chance to use it. Depending on how many files you are dealing with, that may use up a good amount of memory. Also, you don't need the call to `.ToLower` as `IndexText()` is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern Delphi, you can do

```
FOR VAR FileName IN TDirectory.GetFiles('*.bak')+TDirectory.GetFiles('*.zip') DO ...
```

FileName will then be the name (one at a time) of all the *.bak and *.zip in current directory. If you want a specific directory, you can do

```
FOR VAR FileName IN TDirectory.GetFiles(TPath.Combine(Archive,'*.bak'))+TDirectory.GetFiles(TPath.Combine(Archive,'*.zip')) DO ...
```

In all cases, you need to

```
USES System.IOUtils;
```

Comment: Just note that this approach builds up two file lists in memory and then concatenates them into a third list in memory, before you ever get a chance to use the final list. Depending on how many files you are dealing with, that may use up a good amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for multiple file extensions using `Find(First|Next)()`, then you will have to use the wildcard mask `*.*` and then filter the results as needed, eg:

```
var
  s: TSearchRec;
  ext: string

if FindFirst(Archive + '*.*', faNormal or faReadOnly, s) = 0 then
try
  repeat
    if (s.Attr and faDirectory) <> 0 then
      Continue;
    ext := ExtractFileExt(s.Name);
    if SameText(ext, '.bak') or SameText(ext, '.zip') then
    begin
      // use file as needed...
    end;
  until FindNext(s) <> 0;
finally
  FindClose(s);
end;
```

Comment: No need to test for '.' or '..' if you're testing for a directory bit anyway...

Comment: FindClose should be part of a FINALLY block, started at '...= 0 then try'

Comment: @HeartWare "*FindClose should be part of a FINALLY block*" - in *my* example, yes (added). But in the OP's original code, the iteration is clearly broken up into separate sections of code, so one can't assume a `try..finally` is feisable.